# Cosa significa "sprecare" in questo testo?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Superino* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Superino già si guardava sotto il sandalo, se c’era rimasto il grigio della combustione, io stavo ancora attento a come la valle propagava il rumore, quando ci sentimmo addosso la mole del parroco, sbucato da un fitto di felci.
>    
>         Era cosí grande e grosso che **sarebbe stato sprecato** anche nell’artiglieria da montagna, aveva gli occhi piccoli e rossigni come quelli del topo, la carne che scoppiava, le mani grosse e informi come gnocconi di argilla. Portava a spallarm un parasole di cotone giallo, in testa una berretta sbiadita dalla polvere di infinite estati e attraverso la sbottonatura gli si scopriva il petto nudo e fradicio di sudore. La sua tonaca era tutta un rammendo e su ogni rammendo stava ingrappolato un nugolo di mosche dal dorso azzurro, come se uscisse allora da una lunga sosta in una stalla.

Ho cercato il verbo "sprecare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cosa vuol dire che questo grosso parroco "sarebbe stato sprecato anche nell’artiglieria da montagna". Potreste spiegarmelo? Significa forse che il parroco non era adatto a lavorare  nell'artiglieria di montagna?

Comment: Sprecato qui ha il senso di sottoutilizzato. 
Sprecato - 

Usato in modo infruttuoso, sperperato: *denaro sprecato; non valorizzato: sei sprecato in un posto del genere || fiato sprecato; discorso inutile*. (Sabatini Coletti)

Comment: Il parroco sarebbe stato "sottoutilizzato" nell'artiglieria di montagna in che senso, @Gio?

Comment: Potrebbe avere un senso ironico nel contesto, comunque essere sprecato è un’espressione molto comune il cui senso è citato sopra. Il senso è che la persona o la cosa ha maggiori potenzialità di quelle per cui viene impiegato, da cui lo spreco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da Treccani per sprecato participio passato di [sprecare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sprecare/):

> ◆ Part. pass. **sprecato**, anche come agg., usato male, sciupato,
>   consumato inutilmente: *denaro, ingegno, tempo, fiato sprecato*

Dal Sabatini Coletti per [sprecato](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/sprecato.shtml):

> sprecato [spre-cà-to] agg.
>
> •   Usato in modo infruttuoso, sperperato: denaro s.; non valorizzato:
>   sei s. in un posto del genere || fiato s., discorso inutile
>
> •   a. 1838

Sprecato in questo contesto significa usato male, sottoutilizzato rispetto allo scopo prefisso.

Quando si dice *sei sprecato per quel lavoro* significa che hai troppe competenze rispetto a quelle richieste dal lavoro a cui ti hanno destinato. Pensa ad esempio ad un ingegnere nucleare messo a rispondere ad un call center.

Con tutto il rispetto per gli operatori di call center, ovviamente.

Comment: Scusa, @abarisone: tutto questo l'avevo già letto precedentemente e continuo a non capire. In che senso questo parroco si poteva usare meglio o in modo più fruttuoso nell'artiglieria di montagna (o in un altro posto o lavoro)?

Comment: @Charo Un artigliere da montagna di solito è grande e grosso perché deve sopportare molta fatica. Questo parroco era talmente grosso che aveva troppe qualità per quel compito. Quando si dice _sei sprecato per quel lavoro_ significa che hai troppe competenze rispetto a quelle del lavoro a cui ti hanno destinato. Pensa ad esempio ad un ingegnere nucleare messo a rispondere ad un call center. Con tutto il rispetto per gli operatori di call center, ovviamente.

Comment: Quindi, il significato sarebbe che le qualità di robustezza di questo parroco erano talmente eccezionali (capisco che questo è probabilmente detto con ironia) che sarebbe stato meglio affidarli un compito o un lavoro diverso di quello che faceva in quel momento (la frase dice "anche") e persino dell'artigleria da montagna, compito o lavoro in cui si potessero sfruttare meglio le sue qualità. È così?

Comment: @Charo - un conto è il significato e l’uso letterale del termine e un conto è cosa l’autore intende dire. L’interpretazione dell’uso del termine nel brano diventa soggettiva.

Comment: D'accordo, @Gio, cerchiamo di analizzare il significato nel modo più oggettivo possibile. Semplicemente sto cercando di capire il senso della frase "Era cosí grande e grosso che sarebbe stato sprecato anche nell’artiglieria da montagna". Ho scritto veramente qualcosa che sia un'interpretazione soggettiva? Possiamo cambiare "robustezza" per "qualità di essere grande e grosso" se è necessario.

Comment: @Gio: Se il problema è se la frase è o no ironica, lasciamo perdere: questo non è l'oggetto della domanda.

Comment: @abarisone: Se il significato nel contesto del brano della domanda è più o meno quello che ho scritto nel mio commento precedente, potresti aggiungerlo alla tua risposta?